# How do I clear the content of a popup window?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a popup window that shows up when you click on an event on a calendar. On the said popup, I have some textboxes and a list of items that's inside a partial view. Now, my problem is that whenever I select an event that has items on the list then close it and open other events on the calendar, the same items still show up on the other events and its not supposed to because that event has a different id.

How do I clear the item list whenever I close the popup without refreshing the page so that the other events would only display items for the selected event?

This is the part of my code that calls the list

```
var scheduleData = { scheduleId: calEvent.id };
$.ajax({ 
   type: 'POST',
   traditional: true, 
   url: '/Schedule/JsonGetItemsBySchedule/',
   datatype: 'json',
   data: scheduleData,
   success: function (result) {
      var itemlist = result.items; loopItems(itemlist); 
   }
});
```

Comment: When you say "popup" do you mean an additional browser window or an HTML lightbox or similar? More code/insight would be helpful.

Comment: Without knowing more it is hard to tell, but... `.empty()`...?

Comment: What is `result.items.value;` doing? Did you mean to assign it to something?

Comment: Yeah, something similar to lightbox.

Comment: Sorry, the result.items.value was part of a code that was commented out.

Comment: Are you removing the popup on close or just hiding it? If the latter, then the contents will still be there when it opens again, so you need to empty it first. Please show us the code for the popup, since that appears to be the main issue.

Comment: The person who made the popup is no longer around so I'm not 100% sure but from what I understand, it is just hiding. Then there's a method that resets the form so I tried using $dialogContent.find("div[class='partialClass'").val(""); but its not doing what I think it should be doing. The div with the classname partialClass is the container I added for calling the partial view.

Comment: Well, since you're calling a div, `.val("")` will do nothing. Try changing that `.val("")` to `.html("")`. Also `div[class='x']` is not necessary; classes can be called this way: `div.x`

Comment: Wow, that's hard to understand. So many things I don't get... I don't know what `datenow` is; the function assigns `items.innerHTML = items[i].Detail`, which makes no sense. I assume items is some kind of array, since you iterate through it, but then with that line you assign the `.Detail` property of one of those array values to the array itself, thereby overwriting the entire array and (presumably) throwing an error on the next iteration. Also the function you posted doesn't appear to be complete. Please try editing your original post instead of posting it in a comment :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing that out for me. Your suggestion worked. What I did instead was this $('#partialid').html("");

Answer (score 0):

I was having the problem of clearing the content of a Pop-Up aswell.

If you know the ID / have set up a DOM in the pop up with tags (IE: )

You can reference the DOM / Tags and manipulate the content with .innerHTML as you would normally.

For example:
If you wanted to clear the Body:

```
popup.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = '';
```

and if you wanted to clear a Tag:

```
popup.document.getElementsByID('myContent').innerHTML = '';
```

Where

```
    popup = window.open();
    popup.document.write('<body> Content you will not want later <body>');
/
    popup.document.write('<div id = "myContent">Content you will not want later</div>');
```

Respectively

Both methods I have tested on my project,
both methods work.

Reference:
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/139601-solved-clear-popup-windows-content/